# httr request works fine when standalone, stops working when it's a function

Tags: r, httr

This works (HTTP 200):

```
file_data <- upload_file(file_name)
body <- list(
  `file` = file_data,
  `apiKey` = "apiEndpointName"
)
response <- POST(url_upload, body = body, encode = "multipart", handle = handle)
stop_for_status(response)
```

This doesn't (HTTP 400):

```
dl_load <- function(my_api_key, my_file_name) {
  file_data <- upload_file(my_file_name)
  body <- list(
    `file` = file_data,
    `apiKey` = my_api_key
  )
  response <- POST(url_upload, body, encode = "multipart", handle = handle)
  stop_for_status(response)
}
dl_load("apiEndpointName", file_name)
```

What's the difference?

Comment: The second argument to `POST` is `config=`; in the second use, you don't specify `body=body`, just `body`, so you're effectively doing `config=body`.